# Call Different Method Depending On The View Controller Selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Its complicated to put in words but lemme give it a try. I have a MenuViewController that has an array with category names, tapping on the category rows in tableview instantiate a different view controller using the Storyboard ID.

Now if i use different classes for each view controller, that would be a lot of redundant code and classes. What i want to do is to use one class for all these view controllers lets call it PrimaryViewController and upon selecting different categories in the MenuViewController, it calls different methods or blocks in the PrimaryViewController.

Here is the method in the PrimaryViewController:

```
- (void) fetchData:(NSInteger )pageNumber
{        
        channel = [[TheFeedStore sharedStore] fetchWebService:pageNumber withCompletion:^(RSSChannel *obj, NSError *err){

            if (!err) {

                int currentItemCount = [[channel items] count];
                channel = obj;
                int newItemCount = [[channel items] count];

                int itemDelta = newItemCount - currentItemCount;
                if (itemDelta > 0) {
                    NSMutableArray *rows = [NSMutableArray array];

                    for (int i = 0; i < itemDelta; i++) {
                        NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
                        [rows addObject:ip];
                    }
                    [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:rows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
                }
            }
        }];
}
```

The above code has the ability to load one category. Notice the first line "channel = [[TheFeedStore sharedStore] **fetchWebService**", the other categories are named "fetchWebServiceCat2", "fetchWebServiceCat3" and "fetchWebServiceCat4" in another class named TheFeedStore.

What i want is when a different view controller is instantiated from the MenuViewController, it should use PrimaryViewController's fetchData method to call a different category method of TheFeedStore.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[store fetchWebService:webService withCompletion:completion];
```

is equivalent to:

```
[store performSelector:@selector(fetchWebService:withCompletion:)
            withObject:webService
            withObject:completion];
```

So you can do this:

```
SEL sel = nil;

if (...) sel = @selector(fetchWebService:withCompletion:);
if (...) sel = @selector(fetchWebServiceCat2:withCompletion:);
...

[store performSelector:sel withObject:webService withObject:^{}];
```

Or even this:

```
SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"fetchWebService%@:withCompletion:", @"Cat2"]);
...
```

Comment: i m unable to understand how your code can be integrated inside my project